# How do I store positive and negative value (may be separately?) into an array, and print them out?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, java.util.scanner

My program will ask user to enter 10 numbers. The positive numbers are considered as Deposit and negatives numbers are considered as withdraw. After finish, the program should print out the amounts the user has entered.

***My problem is I can't set the logic for storing them into array. I can't figure out how do I separate the positive and negative values into an array.***

This is what I have done so far:

```
package depandwith;

import java.util.*;
public class DepAndWith {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("TO DEPOSIT USE POSITIVE AND, TO WITHDRAW USE NEGATIVE VALUE.\n\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter amount: ");
                int amount[] = new int[10];
                amount[i] = input.nextInt();

                if (amount[i] >= 0) {
                    //store it as deposited
                } else {//if the amount is negative
                    //store it as withdrawn

                }

            }

            //Printing the amounts:
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Print out Deposited amount");
                System.out.println("Print out Withdrawn amount");

            }

        }
}
```

Comment: You can store positive and negative numbers in the same array without needing special code for it.

Comment: Storing the separately even destroys information, the relative sequence of deposits and withdrawals, that may be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is store them normally. While printing take care of it.

```
package depandwith;

import java.util.*;
public class DepAndWith {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("TO DEPOSIT USE POSITIVE AND, TO WITHDRAW USE NEGATIVE VALUE.\n\n");
    int amount[] = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter amount: ");
            amount[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        //Printing the deposit amounts:
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print("Print out Deposited amount");
            if(amount[i]>0){
                System.out.print(amount[i]+", ")
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        //Printing the withdraw amounts:
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Print out Withdraw amount");
            if(amount[i]<0){
                System.out.print(amount[i]+", ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you're creating a new array on each iteration. Move the line

```
int amount[] = new int[10];
```

to outside the loop.

Second, you don't need to handle it differently, you can store any `int` number you want inside an `int` array.

If you insist to separate pos/neg numbers, create two arrays, then separate.. I don't see any reason why you would do that in your case.